# How to find leading number

Tags: c, function

I want to write a function that identifies the leading digit of a integer number.I am confused and in lack of knowledge to write a function for this process.Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

The simple, and naive, solution is to convert the number to a string, and get the first character of the string and convert it back into a number.

Another solution is to divide by ten in a loop, until the result is zero, while remembering the *last* digit of the number. When the result is zero, the last digit is the first digit of the whole number.

Comment: how to convert integer to string?there is no string data type in C.

Comment: @DilankaMadhawa `snprintf`.

Comment: @DilankaMadhawa there are arrays of `char` (see also `snprintf`). But if you choose string conversion instead of division in a loop (which is better), don't forget to negate negative integers (or you get `'-'` as a leading digit of `-42`)

Comment: nope.the numbers input will be 0 or >0.so there wont be negative numbers..I am studying snprintf command.hope ill be able to do it.if I wont ill ask some more help from you. :)

Comment: i dont have any knowledge about buffers.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily in two steps.

1. Change the number to string.
2. Return the first char of the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
int num = 12345;

// left most digit:
int digit = abs(num);
while (digit > 9) {
   digit /= 10;
}

// right most digit:
int digit = abs(num) % 10;
```

Comment: whats the process done by " /= " ?

Comment: same as `digit = digit / 10;`

Comment: `digit /= 10` is the same as `digit = digit / 10`. Although `digit` is not the most appropriate name for this kind of operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel more confortable by using arithmetic instead strings and loops, try this approach:
Calculate the integer part of the base 10 logarithm
Divide the source number by 10 power to the integer part of the log

```
{
    int value = abs(978);

    int valuelog = (int)log10(value);
    int leadingDigit = value / (pow(10,valuelog));

    printf("%d", leadingDigit);
}
```

Example 978:
    log10(978)->2.990; int 2
    pow(10, 2)->100
    978/100->9.78; int 9

Comment: Be careful, 0 is not defined in this algorithm. You should check if input value is 0 and return what you need in that case.

Comment: `pow(10, valuelog)` is a double. I don't think trying to assign a double to an int variable works.

Comment: Yes it works, I tested it. Any way you could cast it before

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int lead(const int number) {
    int divider = 10;
    while (number/divider) {
        divider *= 10; 
    }
    return number/(divider/10);
}

main()
{
    int number = 678;
    int leadNumber = lead(number);
    printf("%d",leadNumber); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int lead_int(const int n) {
    return (abs(n) < 10) ? abs(n) : lead_int(n /10);
}
```

Edited after seeing comments in this post (to include `abs()`), And made this a one lined function.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by converting the integer to string and return the first character.

or you can do a simple program as below.

```
int a;
scanf("%d",&a);
while(a/10>0)
{
 a=a/10
}
printf("leading no. of given input is %d\n",a);
```